# Why in the method of images we solve Poisson's equation instead of Laplace's?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I've checked the solution of the problem of a charge located a certain distance of an infinite grounded conducting plane. One get the solution easily with the method of images. My question is, why we need to solve here Poisson equation and not Laplace? as far as I know, we use Poisson in the presence of volume charge density and in this case there's no such distribution, just a single charge.

Answer (score 1):

Laplace's equation is no more than special case of Poisson's equation with $\rho=0$